# Cast to date then Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I have a `varchar` field which should be date by requirement, it's been loaded manually and the values were not input correctly.

[image]

I use below statement, but get

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
Select cast(c008_instln_start_dt as date).
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to create a specific `CONVERT` for each format, and hope there are only two...

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two distinct formats

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([YourCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2009-03-18')
,('18/03/09')
 
Select * 
      ,AsDate = case when YourCol like '__/__/__' 
                     then try_convert(date,YourCol,3)
                     else try_convert(date,YourCol)
                end
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
YourCol     AsDate
2009-03-18  2009-03-18
18/03/09    2009-03-18
```

Comment: Hi John,

Superb!! 
It works, thank you very much!!

Comment: @stevensun Always happy to help.   As you know by now, storing dates as variable formatted strings is risky.

Comment: @stevensun If you found this answer helpful, you may want to consider ACCEPTING it.   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow